# I have two class, How to find the Number of subclass using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have two class, How to find the Number of subclass using selenium

For Eg:

```
<div class="maincategory">
<div class=subcategory>..</div>
<div class=subcategory>..</div>
<div class=subcategory>..</div>
<div class=subcategory>..</div>
```

Now my task is to identify how many subcategory in this main category

Comment: Please provide more details if you want an answer. Alecxe's answer should be the answer given what you have supplied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all of the subcategories with a `div.maincategory > div.subcategory` CSS selector and use `size()` to determine how much of them were found:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.maincategory > div.subcategory")).size();
```

This is assuming you have only one "main category".

Comment: Hi alecxe, it's not giving the correct value. is there any other way I can get it?

Comment: @ravi I suspect that some of the subcategories are present, but invisible. Can you post the real contents of the div with class="maincategory"?

Comment: @ravi okay, what are you trying to achieve exactly? What elements to count?

Comment: @ravi okay, how about `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.product")).size();`?

Comment: it gives output as 51 but i have 62 products

Comment: @ravi it's difficult to tell without actually seeing the complete HTML source of the page. Can you share the link to the web page?

Comment: its not hosted, or is there any way i can get the last product's xpath?

Comment: It's a guessing game. There could be multiple reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take by xpath.
 The xpath should be like `html\div\div[N]` N is the number of each sub-class from maincategory. So, in your code, you can do a `for` to read the xpath and select the last subcategory class. I think that this can help you

Comment: hi Pedro, can you explain with the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Finally @alecxe answer solved the problem, it was not updating because of page dynamic loading during the page scroll, did a full end scroll and later queried for the value and got the desired value... Thanks all for spending your time to solve the problem